# User-defined type not defined when used in form?

Tags: excel, vba

Updated the question after suggestion below, but still have the same problem.

I'm trying to get my label txtFullName caption to display the name of my type Customer name element when the customers ID is selected in combobox, but when I try to access the type elements from the combobox change sub it tells me it's not a decleared sub or function?

In module:

```
Type Customer
    Name as string
End Type

Dim Customer() as Customer
Dim size as Integer

Sub ExampleStart()

    size = Sheets("Customers").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ReDim Customer(size)

    For i = 0 To size
        With Customer(i)
            .Name = cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        End With
    Next

    ExampleForm.Show

End Sub
```

In Example Form:

```
Private Sub ExampleForm_Initialize()

    For i = 0 To size
        ExampleForm.comboboxCustomer.AddItem (Customer(i).Name) '<-Fails!
    Next

End Sub
```

The compile error tells Sub or Function has not been defined, even tho I clearly have it defined outside any private sub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring the `Customer()` array within the `UserForm_Initialize` event handler means that the array is not accessible from anywhere outside that event handler. Move the `Dim Customer() As Customer` statement to the top of the module just after the `End Type` line. This will make the array visible to every event handler in the form module

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by setting Customer() and size to Public

```
Type Customer
    Name as string
End Type

Public Customer() as Customer 'instead of Dim
Public size as Integer 'instead of Dim
```

Now elements of type Customer can be accessed from within the userform